# How to merge annaul datasets into a panel?

Tags: merge, sas, panel

I'm rather new to SAS and hope that you can help me out with this rather simple question. I have 7 annual datasets, one for each year between 2007 and 2013, which each contains a number of variables including an id for each firm within the dataset. At first i have to load these 7 datasets from a folder on my computer and next transform them in to a panel in which i have an observation for each firm each year, such that it appears somehow like this:

```
FIRM ID REVENUE EMPLOYED    YEAR
1   2,5 3   2007
1   2,6 3   2008
1   2,8 3   2009
2   1   2   2007
2   0,8 2   2008
2   0,8 2   2009
2   0,9 2   2010
2   0,8 1   2011
2   0,9 1   2012
2   0,9 2   2013
3   3,5 5   2007
3   3,5 5   2008
3   3,5 5   2009
3   3,6 5   2010
3   3,6 5   2011
3   3,7 5   2012
3   3,6 5   2013
```

I have tried to google for a solution, but haven't found one yet, and would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Bests,
Mathilde

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please include your code and the community will help you with any change required.

Comment: If you have 8  datasets, one for each year between 2007-2013, that's probably the first problem you should look at...

Answer (score 1):

Combining datasets is done many ways, but the simplest is simply using the `set` statement and specifying each dataset.

```
data want;
  set have2007 have2008 have2009;
  by firmID;
run;
```

You can also use a `-` to avoid writing each one out.

```
data want;
  set have2007-have2013;
  by firmID;
run;
```

Only if they are sequential and the number is at the end, though.

If you want to know what year they're from, the `INDSNAME` option will give you a variable that contains the dataset name, and you can derive the year from that.

Comment: But isn't this solution going to join the datasets horizontally? So that there would be one observation for each firm containing the datapoints for each year instead of one observation for each year (I'm sorry for the rather horribly looking table I have tried to include, but the point is that each firm should be represented each year for which there is a datapoint in one of the eight datasets)

Comment: `set`is vertical. `merge` is horizontal.

Comment: Thanks! But when I include the indsname just below the by-element, all spaces turn up blank instead. Could I get around this problem in some other way?

Comment: `indsname` is a `set` statement option.  It isn't its own statement.  Look it up.